# How to retrieve Tincan Statements sent to Scorm using php, to the WordPress Dashboard?

Tags: tin-can-api

I have send the Tincan Statements to Scorm Cloud now how can i retrieve the statements from Scorm to my WordPress Dashboard? through this code $answer=$lrs->queryStatements(['agent' => $actor]); i can retrieve all the content but how to retrieve exact statement like for e.g.
 User created a New Course ???

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional query parameters to the array passed to `queryStatements`. In your case it seems like you would pass the Agent, Verb ID, and potentially an Activity ID if you know the course ahead of time. To an extent it will depend on how the Activity Provider has constructed the statements. If you don't have the Activity ID ahead of time you may have to check the returned statement(s) for an Activity Definition "type" property matching a "course" IRI for instance. The parameters available in the `queryStatements` call should match the parameters available in the GET /statements resource from the specification. See the table here:

https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec/blob/master/xAPI.md#stmtapiget